# winter 21 release -Changed Permissions for Linked Articles

Tags: release-notes, winter21

As per [Winter'21 release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter21/release-notes/rn_knowledge_article_perm.htm) ,

> Access to linked articles in the API is limited to users with access to the Knowledge article.

what does this mean and how can I test in the org?